# IMAP: Search by a UID range on Exchange server seems to be broken

Tags: exchange-server, imap

I'm using message UID values to sync an IMAP mailbox with my application. The mail server is Microsoft Exchange Server 2013. 
According to the IMAP specification, UID numbers should be in a strictly ascending order. However, at times I have found that the search result for a range of UID values returns a number outside the range specified.

```
=> 'A8 UID SEARCH UID 126095:*'
<= '* SEARCH 126026'
<= 'A8 OK SEARCH completed.
```

It looks like a bug to me. Has anyone encountered this issue and is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That result is legal provided that 126026 is the highest UID in the mailbox. You can try it with any IMAP server. Put one message in a new empty mailbox, then run `a uid search uid 999999:*`, `a uid search uid 2:1` or `a uid search uid 1:2`. The key is that 1:2 is the same as 2:1; UID arguments are sets.

The server is required to *assign* UIDs in strictly ascending order as new messages are added to a mailbox. Clients are free to *reference* messages in any order. (Note that servers may return messages in an order which differs from that in the client's command.)

Comment: This answer was extremely helpful. I was testing and was going nuts trying to figure out why UID 600:* was bringing back 456 every single time. I then added another test e-mail and saw that UID 600:* brought back the newly incremented 457. So the latest e-mail will always be included when using a range query, regardless if it is less than your specified range. Thank you

Comment: That's not what happens... if the last message has UID 456, then 600:*, 600:456 and 456:600 are three ways to say the same thing, and asking for any of them will return all of the _existing_ messages in that range, _including both boundaries_. 455:456 returns two messages, 455:600 returns two, 456:600 returns one, and 457:600 returns zero.

Comment: If the max UID is 457, and I use 600:*, I should expect to see just UID 457, correct?

Comment: @ErkinDjindjiev yes, precisely.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed to know, although I may not have described it accurately in my comment.